# Sorting in O(n) time in a finite domain

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, sorting, radix-sort

I've been stuck with this problem for 2 weeks. Any idea of how to aproach it?.

> Let $L$ be a list of $n$ different integer numbers, assume that the elements of $L$ are in the range $[1,750]$. Design a linear ordering algorithm to order the elements of $L$.

I already tried with insertion sort. But I'm not sure if my approach is right:

- Construct an array of bits. Initialize them to zero.
- Read the input, for each value you see set the respective bit in the array to 1.
- Scan the array, for each bit set, output the respective value.

Complexity: $O(2n) = O(n)$

I also wanted to use radix sort but I can't understand how to apply it, any idea?

Comment: Your idea with the bitvector is heading in a good direction.  But what happens if the list $L$ contains duplicates, e.g., if it contains the number 42 twice?  Your algorithm will only output 42 once, which isn't quite right.  (For instance, if the input list is 3,42,5,42, your algorithm will output 3,5,42, which isn't quite what we want: the correct answer is 3,5,42,42.)  Can you spot any way to fix up that problem?

Comment: Your idea of using radix sort is also a reasonable direction to think about.  What do you know about the runtime of radix sort?  What is the running time of radix sort?  What parameters does its running time depend upon?

Comment: Comparison based sorting can't sort in less than O(nlogn), but if number of values is bounded by D, you can sort in O(D*n), or O(n) if you consider D as constant. Any idea of how can i solve it :(

Comment: winston, huh?  I don't follow you.  As far as ideas for how you can solve it, come on: I just gave you two ideas!  Perhaps you should spend some quality time thinking about them in depth before asking for more?  Separately: I'm not sure why you believe that the running time of comparison-based sorting is relevant; I assume you already know that neither of the sorting approached you mentioned in the question statement are comparison-based sorts, right?

Comment: You could use Counting Sort, which can sort $n$ numbers in the range [1,..., k] in $O(n)$ when $k = O(n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Bitvector approach is correct solution.

Problem statement tells that you are given $n$ **different** integers so there is no need to count multiple occurrence of number in sequence. This also allows you to cut down needed storage to $\lceil{\frac{750}{8}}\rceil = 94$ bytes.

Now the algorithm:

Input: $A$ - array of unique integers, 1 based

Output: None - we update given array

```
B[750] = 0; bitvector of len 750 initially set to 0
for each i in A
    B[i] = 1
k = 1
for j = 1 to 750
    if B[j]
        A[k] = j
        k = k+1
```

This obviously runs in $O(n)$ and uses $O(1)$ memory.

This can run in linear time because it isn't compare based sorting. As you correctly pointed out every compare based sorting must take at least $O(n \log n)$ steps.

This approach is special case of bucket sorting but we used information about problem statement (namely: unique integers and range of those integers)

Comment: This clearly solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Read numbers into array L
Initialize array of numbers D with with size of 750 and set all its values to 0

for each value in L do
  increase value of D at index value by 1
end loop

Initialize array of numbers ResultltArray

iterate over i from 1 to 750
  from 0 to value of D at index i do
    push i to ResultltArray
  end loop
end loop

return ResultltArray
```

Comment: You are not using the fact that integers are unique. Initializing $N$ as random number might it set $N$ to number bigger then 750, this by Pigeonhole principle
will validate assumption that number are unique.

Comment: "Interrupt" should be "iterate" (several times), and "resoult" should be "result". Also, $N$ is not random but arbitrary and given, and the array $L$ is not random but an input. Finally, the array $D$ is not a person, so all "its" values should be zeroed.

Comment: @Bartek you are right... Missed that.

Comment: I don't understand. If you assume that all integers in $L$ are distinct, then we know that the size of $L$ can't be bigger than 750. Since the size is bounded by a constant, any sorting algorithm on $L$ will take O(1) time. :-)